# print reflowed p:dataTable on normal format using p:printer

Tags: primefaces, printing, datatable

I have the following code

```
<p:dataTable id="table" reflow="true">
    ...
</p:dataTable>

<p:commandButton>
    <p:printer target="table" />
<p:commandButton>
```

is there a way to print the table with its normal format even if it is in reflow mode(each row as a stack)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I end up doing

I created a function to modify jquery print function to format my table as I wanted it before print it

```
function formatTableBeforePrint() {
$.fn.jqprint = (function() {

    var cached_function = $.fn.jqprint;

    return function(d) {
        $.fn.jqprint.defaults = {
            debug : false,
            importCSS : true,
            printContainer : true,
            operaSupport : true
        };
        var tables = $('.ui-datatable-reflow');
        $(".ui-datatable-reflow .ui-datatable-data td .ui-column-title").addClass('noprint');
        tables.removeClass('ui-datatable-reflow');
        var result = cached_function.apply(this, arguments);
        tables.addClass('ui-datatable-reflow');
        return result;
    };
  })();
}
```

and then called that function from my `p:commandButton`

```
<p:commandButton onclick="formatTableBeforePrint()">
    <p:printer target="table" />
<p:commandButton>
```

Comment: Please create an issue in PF that responsiveness should not block normal printing

Comment: @Kukeltje, I don't think that this is really an issue in PF since the `p:printer` is doing what it's suppose to do, to print the elements that are displayed in the page as they are.

Comment: But should it not take the 'real-estate' as available in the physical page of the printer? So if reflow there would not be needed it should not have the corresponding css/media-queries applied (or maybe I do not understand jqprint  in the `p:printer` completely, never used it/had the need)

Comment: jqprint takes the styles that applies to the device's screen size and not the ones that would apply to the  physical page of the printer unless `@media print` is define in which case will take those, and since `p:printer` is just a wrapper for jqprint it will work the same way.

Comment: Ok, clear but should/coud PF then not create a `@media print` for 'reflowed' components in some way? Or did you try that yourself and did ot fail?

Comment: I think I tried but didn't work, don't remember why, this was some time ago, i just post the answer because someone left a comment saying that had the same problem.